# how to pass dropdown list value to a function as a parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one dropdown list, on the ng-change event I need to pass the dropdown list value to the `$scope.getPIRData` function so that I can get dynamic results.

```
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-offset-4" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <select class="form-control"  ng-model="sel_val" ng-change="getPIRData(sel_val)" ng-options="data.deveui for data in Customers"></select>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
            $scope.sel_val = 0;
            $scope.DefaultLabel = "Loading.....";
            var post = $http({
                method: "get",
                url: "../data.json",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {},
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
            });
            post.success(function (data, status) {
                $scope.Customers = data;

            });
            post.error(function (data, status) {
            });
            $scope.getPIRData = function (id) {
                $http.get("/PIRDetails/GetPIRStatus/" + id)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
                        console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.myWelcome));
                    });
            };
        });
    </script>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9srG9.png)

Comment: try sending `sel_val.deveui`, i.e., `ng-change="getPIRData(sel_val.deveui)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the value in the ng-change directive.

```
ng-change="getPIRData(sel_val)"
```

Comment: its showing something like this - /PIRDetails/GetPIRStatus/[object%20Object] and getting error. expected value - e8e1102d9

Comment: What's the structure for `Customers`? The above error just means that `sel_val` is an array of object. Add a `console.log(id)` before the $http call in `getPIRData` function and tell me the output.

Comment: That's not helping, could you take a screenshot or at least format the output properly?